# Cannot add user from form in spring boot security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new to Spring boot. I'm trying to get user information from SignUp form and then save it to the database. But when I fill details on the signup page, it redirects to login/signup page and no data is added to the database with no errors and logs. 
 Following is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"   xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">

<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>xyzSite</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom-styling.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/FormStyling.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Favicons -->
<link href="img/logo.png" rel="icon">
<link href="img/logo.png" rel="ResumeFlexer_Icon">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="margin-bottom: -20px;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">RESUME FLEXER</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="recent">Recent Post</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="donate">Donate</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up / Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="parallax_full">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- ################################################### -->
      <!--      LogIn Form        -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 login-style">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">
            <label style="color:red">Invalid username and Password</label>
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
            <label>You have been logged out</label>
        </div>
        <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">

          <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="pssword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Log In"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>  <!-- Login div end -->
      <hr>
      <!-- ################################################### -->
      <!--      Sign Up Form      -->
      <section id="SignUp">
      <div class="col-xs-12 SignUp">
        <h1>Not a Member? <br>Create Your Account!</h1>
        <p>It's Free !</p>
        <form action="adduser" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name"> Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ex: Steves Jobs" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="emailId">Email Id</label>
            <input type="mail Id" class="form-control" id="emailId" name="emailId"
                placeholder="Email" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone_no">Phone No.</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_no" name="phone_no" placeholder="Phone Number" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob">Date Of Birth</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control dobDate" name="dob" id="dob"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name ="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
          </div>
          <label>Gender</label>
            <div class="radio">
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" checked>Male</label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender">Female</label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender">Other</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="field">Field</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="field" name="field"
                placeholder="Software Engineering or Data Science, etc."/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nationality">Nationality</label>
                <input type="nationality" class="form-control" id="nationality" name="nationality"
                placeholder="Indian / English / American"/>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <nobr><input type="checkbox" id="termsAndCondition" name="termsAndCondition" value="agreed" required><a href="/termsAndCondition" style="color:#fff;"> Terms and Conditions</a></nobr>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Create Account"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>

    </row>
  </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- Wrapper div ending -->

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src = "js/customLoginValidation.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Controller mapping signup form**

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/adduser")
    public String addUser(@RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("username") String username,
        @RequestParam("emailId") String email,
        @RequestParam("phone_no") String phone_no,
        @RequestParam("dob") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date dob,
        @RequestParam("password") String password,
        @RequestParam("gender") String gender,
        @RequestParam("field") String field,
        @RequestParam("nationality") String nationality,
        @RequestParam("termsAndCondition") String termsAndCondition) {
    System.out.println("addUser() method called");
    User user = new User(username,name,password,email,phone_no,field,dob,gender,nationality,new Date());
    userservice.addUser(user);
    return "user/profile";
}
```

**Security Configuration**

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("**/login"))
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/profile").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/","/faq","/donate","/recent","/signup").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .successHandler(successHandler())
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/profile")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .permitAll();   
}
```

Comment: When you use form with method="post" data is sended in body of request, not in request params. replace method params to @RequestBody User user

Comment: Are you posting using @RequestParam and where is your dao class? Post the network call of ajax(I assume it is ajax)

Comment: How can I map input values to java object using @RequestBody? Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is POSTed to `/adduser`. As for as I can see the path `/adduser` is not permitted in the security config. Try adding

```
.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/adduser/**").permitAll()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are submitting the form on `/adduser`. But it's not authorized and as a result you are probably getting an `HTTP.Unauthorized` 401 Status code. Can you also authorize `/adduser` route in Security Configuration like below?

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("**/login"))
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/profile").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")   

        .antMatchers("/adduser/**").permitAll();  // <- add this line

        .antMatchers("/","/faq","/donate","/recent","/signup").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .successHandler(successHandler())
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/profile")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .permitAll();   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems enpoint `/adduser` is performing task for adding user in you application. Try doing two things in you code base.

1. Make an entry in Security Config for endpoint `/adduser`.

`.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/adduser/**").permitAll()`

2. Put Condition in your controller code i.e only when user is added then it will return to `user/profile`.

`if(userservice.addUser(user)){
    return "user/profile";
}`